# Напишите программу, которая получает на вход три целых числа, по одному числу в строке

Tags: python

Задание:

> Напишите программу, которая получает на вход три целых числа, по
>   одному числу в строке, и выводит на консоль в три строки сначала
>   максимальное, потом минимальное, после чего оставшееся число. На ввод
>   могут подаваться и повторяющиеся числа.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
l = [a,b,c]
if ((max(l) == c and max(l) == b) or (max(l) == a and max(l) == b) or (max(l) == a and max(l) == c)):
    print(max(l),min(l),max(l),sep="\n")
elif ((min(l) == c and min(l) == b) or (min(l) == a and min(l) == b) or (min(l) == a and min(l) == c)):          
    print(max(l),min(l),min(l), sep="\n")
elif a < b < c:
    print(max(l),min(l), b, sep="\n")
elif b < a < c: 
    print(max(l),min(l), a, sep="\n")
elif b < c < a:
    print(max(l),min(l), c, sep="\n")
elif c < b < a:
    print(max(l),min(l), b, sep="\n")
elif a < c < b:
    print(max(l),min(l), c, sep="\n")
elif c < a < b:
    print(max(l),min(l), b, sep="\n")
```

Comment: В чем может быть проблема? Один из тестов показывает, что не правильно

Comment: Какое конкретно условие задачи? Если судить по заголовку, то задача у вас решена тремя первыми строчками кода.

Comment: Могут повторяться

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полное условие задачи.

Comment: Напишите программу, которая получает на вход три целых числа, по одному числу в строке, и выводит на консоль в три строки сначала максимальное, потом минимальное, после чего оставшееся число.

На ввод могут подаваться и повторяющиеся числа.

Comment: `min_v, mid_v, max_v = sorted(l); print(max_v, min_v, mid_v, sep='\n')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Код:***

```py
l = list(map(int, (input() for i in range(3))))

print(max(l))
l.remove(max(l))

print(min(l))
l.remove(min(l))

print(l[0])
```

Для того, чтобы получить 3 числа я использовал замысловатую конструкцию:

```py
list(map(int, (input() for i in range(3))))
```

Но она полностью идентична 4-ём первым строкам в Вашем коде. Можете её заменить на своё усмотрение.

Для печати элементов я воспользовался теми же функциями, что и Вы: `min` и `max`.
Но я решил удалять из списка использованные элементы, чтобы не возникало никаких проблем. Это позволило мне сократить код и полностью избавиться от условий.